# Protege multiple equivalentTo axioms vs union of axioms

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

I am trying to understand the difference between using multiple equivalentTo axioms and using a union (i.e., disjunction) of those axioms. I have set up a toy ontology with this structure:

  `Class_A
   - Class_A.1
  Class_B
  Class_C
  Class_D
   - Class_D.1`

with an object property named `has_part`.

`Class_A.1` is defined using the equivalence axiom:

  `EquivalentTo
  (Class_A and (has_part some Class_B)) or (Class_A and (has_part some Class_C))`

`Class_D1` is defined using two equivalence axioms:

  `EquivalentTo
  Class_D and (has_part some Class_B)`


  `EquivalentTo
  Class_D and (has_part some Class_C)`

Using HermiT 1.3.8.413, I execute the DL Query `has_part some Class_B`.
This returns subclass `Class_D.1`, which makes sense.

However, I do not understand why `Class_A.1` was not returned. I thought since the equivalence axioms for `Class_A.1` was a disjunction, it was be subsumed by the `has_part some Class_B` disjunct.

Comment: Multiple `A EquivalentTo B_1, A EquivalentTo B_2, ..., A EquivalentTo B_n, ` the same as  `A SubClassOf (B_1 and B_2 and ... and B_n)` as well as `(B_1 or B_2 or ... or B_n) SubClassOf A`

Comment: Why should `Class_A.1` be returned? `A EquivalentTo B` is syntactic sugar for `A SubClassOf B` and `B SubClassOf A`. For your example, the important part is `Class_A.1 SubClassOf (Class_A and (has_part some Class_B)) or (Class_A and (has_part some Class_C))` It is the intersection, thus, a reasoner could not infer that `Class_A.1 SubClassOf (Class_A and (has_part some Class_B))` which would be necessary for your query

Comment: Shorter version: fo `Class_A.1` to be returned, the query needs to be `Class_A and has_part some Class_B`

Comment: @Ignazio Are you sure that this would change anything? I mean `A SubClassOf B or C` with a query `B` won't return `A` as subclass, or am I wrong?

Comment: @AKSW you're right, I was reading the query in reverse.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try a simpler example. We don't necessarily need to bring in object properties to illustrate the concept. We can replace 'has_part some X' with an arbitrarily named class with no change to entailments, since we're not saying anything about X. Also for the purposes of your example, we can leave out the 'A' in list of intersection elements.

Instead of your A.1, let's try:

```
Prokaryote EquivalentTo Bacteria OR Archaea
```

Choosing a biological example as I know you're familiar, but for others, Bacteria, Archaea and Eukaryota are the 3 domains of life. The term "prokaryote" refers to an artificial but sometimes useful grouping of bacteria and archaea.

OK, so now we try the DL query "Bacteria". This doesn't return prokaryotes as a subclass, as we know that actually prokaryotes are a *superclass* of bacteria.

Hopefully mapping to this concrete example helps with the underlying intuition. I personally find that UnionOf can be strangely counter-intuitive with abstract examples, but when replaced with concrete examples it's more obvious.

For a more formal elucidation, I think it suffices to echo ASKW's comments, that equivalence entails mutual subClassOf, but there is no entailment that `A subClassOf B or C` entails `A subClassOf B`. Hope this helps.